# Fetch all lines until a date using sed, except for the last matching line

Tags: sed, files

I need to fetch lines from a file using sed but I don't want the last line to be printed. What shall I add in this command to do so?

`sed "/$START_DATE/q" user.log>test2.log`

Comment: `sed "/$START_DATE/q" user.log>test2.log | head -n -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it feels more intuitive, you could add a second `sed` to the pipeline whose only job is to delete the last line (matched by the previous/existing `sed`):

```
sed "/$START_DATE/q" user.log | sed '$d' > test2.log
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU sed, you can replace `q` with `Q`:

> Q [exit-code]
>
> ```
> This command accepts only one address.
>
> This command is the same as q, but will not print the contents of pattern space.
> ```

So `sed "/$START_DATE/Q" user.log>test2.log`

---

Otherwise, you can turn off default print and print the lines before quitting explicitly:

```
sed -n '/Line 10/q; p'
```